# Do modern browsers support base64 encoded JS or CSS chunks in HTML like they do for images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, base64

I'm writing an HTML mail viewer which gets MIME source on input (with HTML mail body and related objects attached). I would like to base64 encode all embedded objects (like images which appear in the message). However, I'm not sure if it's gonna work with other types of embedded resources like CSS or JS files.

Although it's not common for emails to have CSS or JS as separate files attached to the message (rather than be included directly in HTML), this is still possible and I want my mail viewer to be prepared to this situation.

For now, I'm planning to find things like cid:some-content-id in tag attributes in HTML body and replace all occurrences with base64 encoded bodies of corresponding embedded objects (which have the same content-id in headers of the corresponding object). In this approach I don't even bother what kind of a resource I'm dealing with now (be it image or whatever, I just run regex pattern match). But if it turns out that this method does not work for anything but images, I need to find another solution.

Comment: CSS and JS are already plain text, why would you need to base64 them?

Comment: How can I write <script src="something here"> without utilizing base64 encoding otherwise? Remember, my code just replaces cid:something in <script src="cid:something">, it does not build the entire tags. Anyway, it would be easier to use the same code for all kinds of replacements so that my code wouldn't need to understand if it currently operates on IMG (which definitely needs base64) or SCRIPT. It's just a regex match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, browsers support [DATA URLs](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php) (which can be base 64) in place of actual files.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64,Ym9keXtiYWNrZ3JvdW5kOmJsYWNrO2NvbG9yOndoaXRlO30="></link>

<script src="data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,d2luZG93LmFsZXJ0KCJ0aGlzIGlzIGV4ZWN1dGVkIGZybSBiYXNlNjQiKTs="></script>

<p>This text is styled white from the data-uri loaded css</p>
```

That said, Javascript is generally not allowed in emails and CSS can simply be copied into `<style>` tags, so this is not necessary in your situation.